# Demographic makeup of Barrayar

Tags: vorkosigan-saga

I seem to recall that Bujold mentions four primary culture groups on Barrayar: Russian, 'Greekies', and English, but I can't remember or find any mention of the fourth group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The fourth group are the French

From "[Captain Vorpatril's Alliance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Vorpatril%27s_Alliance)":

> “Barrayaran Greekie?” asked Rish, brows rising in puzzlement.
>
> “The smallest of our main languages,” he [Vorpatril] told her. “**The Firsters
>   actually arrived in four disparate settlement groups—Russian, British,
>   French and Greek**, as their home regions on Old Earth were back then.
>   Over the centuries of the Time of Isolation, everyone pretty much
>   blended together genetically...

Comment: Also French names like Piotr **Pierre** Vorkosigan, Etienne Vorsoisson, etc.

Comment: Also in *Barrayar* (Chapter 12) one of the soldiers lost in the cave exclaims "Merde. Perdu!"